# fileOut.Write object does not support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA project in Excel and trying to output text to a txt file. However, I encountered a "object doesn't support this property or method" error at the fileOut.Write.

Would like to know if my fileOut.Write correct?

```
Dim fso, fileOut As Object



'Begin writing backup script
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fileOut = fso.CreateTextFile(currentWorkbookPath & "\" & srrNumber & "_bkp.txt", True, False)


fileOut.Write = "#!/bin/sh -x" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
```

Comment: Add a reference to the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library, and declare `fso As FileSystemObject`. You'll get *IntelliSense*, autocompletion, compile-time validation, and you can browse the existing members in the *Object Browser* (F2). There's no reason to late-bind the scripting runtime unless you intend to run your code on a Mac.

Comment: Alternatively, refer to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object); `FileSystemObject.CreateTextFile` yields a [`TextStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/textstream-object) object, which has a `WriteLine` method.

Comment: hi, u have to write like thie fileOut.Write ("#!/bin/sh -x" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileSystemObject.CreateTextFile` yields a `TextStream` object, which does have a [`Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/write-method) *method* (it also has a `WriteLine` method)... but you're using it as if it were an assignable *property*.

Just remove the `=` assignment operator.

```
fileOut.Write "#!/bin/sh -x" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
```

(note: no need for any parentheses)

---

Note that this declares `fileOut` as an `Object`, while leaving `fso` as an implicit `Variant`:

```
Dim fso, fileOut As Object
```

You want to declare an explicit type for all variables:

```
Dim fso As Object, fileOut As Object
```

...and ideally avoid declaring multiple variables in a single instruction:

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim fileOut As Object
Set fileOut = fso.CreateTextFile(currentWorkbookPath & "\" & srrNumber & "_bkp.txt", True, False)

fileOut.Write content
```

Lastly, note that the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library has no reason to not be referenced in VBA. In the editor's Tools menu, select "References..." and find the type library in the list. Then work with the actual types:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

Dim fileOut As TextStream
Set fileOut = fso.CreateTextFile(currentWorkbookPath & "\" & srrNumber & "_bkp.txt", True, False)

fileOut.Write content
```

Notice when the actual object types are used, you get the list of available members when you type the `.` (dot) operator: this completely eliminates run-time error 438, forever. When you work against `Object`, member calls can only be resolved at run-time (i.e. "late" binding), which is more error prone especially if you're unfamiliar with the library you're using.

There's no need to ever use late binding with the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library, unless you intend to run your code on a Mac.